# Strapi x Next.js page on slug “/” is not showing

Tags: next.js, strapi

I’m building a website using Strapi and Next.js. The website is built on top of the restaurant starter made by strapi.

I’m encountering a strange issue when adding pages…
When I add a page with a slug such as “myAwesomePage” everything is working. But as I’m trying to add a home page with a slug set to “” (nothing), the page won’t show up and constantly brings up a 404 error.

Have anyone already experienced this issue/ know how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

In NextJs the routes name cannot be blank, it would result in error.If you want to navigate to the path "/", You need to create a index.ts/index.js file in your pages folder. That way you will be able to access the ("/"), which would be localhost:port on your local machine.

Alternatively you can create a home.ts/home.js file in your pages folder which would route you to localhost:port/home.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! 
At least it helps me understanding what the problem is.

The only thing I still don't figured out, is how to set this so it won't mess with my internationalization...